# Select field working with onclick without button in php

Tags: javascript

I want to select a option and it will work without button. According to my code it is working onchange. I want it will work onclick.  How can I do this?

```
<select name="cdate" size="1" class="selhead" id="cdate" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <?php 

      $sql2=mysql_query("select distinct cdate from coach_shedule where route='$route' order by cdate");
      while($data2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
      {
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $data2['cdate']; ?>" <?php if($data2['cdate']==$cdate) {echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo $data2['cdate']; ?></option>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: Just add a submit button, and it will work right out of the box, as the change event is submitting the form.

Comment: You change onchange="blabla" to onclick="blabla"? Btw, your code looks mighty SQL-injectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must assign the onclick event to every member of the selectbox:

```
<option value="some PHP" selected="selected?" onclick="this.parentNode.form.submit()">More PHP code</option>
```

However, in my browser the `onchange` event for `<select>` works just fine. I wonder what's your point.

Comment: In my browser the    onchange event for     <select> is also working but I want it will work onclick. And thanks for your suggestion. I have applied your code and it's working.